# Cascading Dropdown in Javascript and can't get them in CodeBehind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a code in Javascript for cascading dropdown but the problem is I can't access the data in the CodeBehind in C# web.

This is my code in **javascript**:

```
function CollegeDepartment() {
    var s1 = document.getElementById("college");
    var s2 = document.getElementById("department");
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    if (s1.value == "College of Engineering") {
        var optionArray = ["Civil Engineering", "Computer Engineering", "Electrical Engineering", "Electronics and Communication Engineering", "Industrial Engineering", "Mechanical Engineering"];
    } else if (s1.value == "CAS") {
        var optionArray = ["Political Science", "Mascomm", "Liacomm"];
    } else if (s1.value == "Commerce") {
        var optionArray = ["Business Ad", "Hotel Management", "Tourism"];
    } else if (s1.value == "Education") {
        var optionArray = ["SPED"];
    } else if (s1.value == "CICCT") {
        var optionArray = ["Computer Science", "Information Technology"];
    }

    for (var option in optionArray) {
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = optionArray[option];
        newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[option];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
};
```

And I have that code in **aspx**:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" name="college" id="college" runat="server" oninput="CollegeDepartment()" style="width:300px;">
    <option selected>Select College</option>
    <option value="College of Engineering">College of Engineering</option>
    <option value="CAS">Colpxlege of Arts and Science</option>
    <option value="Commerce">College of Commerce</option>
    <option value="Education">College of Education</option>
    <option value="CICCT">CICCT</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <select id="department" name="department" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Department" style="width:300px;">
    <option value="Department" selected>Select Department</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

How can I access the dynamic value of the dropdown?

Comment: when you want to access the data ? On a button click or drop down change ?

Comment: @nichu09 onclick of the button

Comment: if you are making ajax call to code behind, you can't access the drop down value.you have to pass the value from client side. Normal button click event working using your code with out any problem.

Comment: @nichu09 I don't know how to make the ajax call.